# Dynamic assignment of methods in python class

Tags: python

I want to create a bunch of methods in class `__init__` method dynamically. Havent had luck so far.

CODE:

```
class Clas(object):
    def __init__(self):
        for i in ['hello', 'world', 'app']:
            def method():
                print i
            setattr(self, i, method)
```

Than I crate method and call method that is fitst in list.

```
>> instance = Clas()

>> instance.hello()

'app'
```

I expect it to print `hello` not `app`. WHat is the problem? 
In addition, each of these dynamically assigned methods referred to the same function in memory, even if I do `copy.copy(method)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to bind `i` properly:

```
for i in ['hello', 'world', 'app']:
    def method(i=i):
        print i
    setattr(self, i, method)
```

The `i` variable then is made local to `method`. Another option is to use a new scope (separate function) generating your method:

```
def method_factory(i):
    def method():
        print i
    return method 

for i in ['hello', 'world', 'app']:
    setattr(self, i, method_factory(i))
```